# Twisted simulate timer with callback

Tags: python, callback, twisted

I am new to twisted and i wanted to simulate a timer or something of the sort.

What i have is:

```
def whatToCall():
    print 'Before: ' + str(len(globals.session_manager))
    for ses in globals.session_manager:
        if ses.expired is True:
            globals.session_manager[ses.id] = None
    print 'After: ' + str(len(globals.session_manager))
    reactor.callLater(15, whatToCall(), None)

def callBacks():
    reactor.callLater(15, whatToCall(), None)
....
#: Start the reactor
    reactor.callWhenRunning(callBacks())
    reactor.listenTCP(globals.port, factory)
    reactor.run()
```

Firstly, the first time i call is not taking 15 seconds. Secondly, this is obviously not working. I understand the concept of callback chains and deferred but having some struggle with this.

Basically i want to check if any session expired from time to time and want to schedule it every time.

Solved: Use twisted tasks:

```
def checkForExpiredSessions():
   print 'Before: ' + str(len(globals.session_manager))
   for i, ses in enumerate(globals.session_manager):
      if ses.expired is True:
         del globals.session_manager[i]
   print 'After: ' + str(len(globals.session_manager))


def callBacksRun():
  l = task.LoopingCall(checkForExpiredSessions)
  l.start(15.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression:

```
reactor.callWhenRunning(callBacks())
```

first **calls** `callBacks` and then passes the return value to `reactor.callWhenRunning`.  Something similar is true for:

```
reactor.callLater(15, whatToCall(), None)
```

`reactor.callWhenRunning` and `reactor.callLater` both accept callable objects as an argument.  Unless you expect `callBacks` to return a callable object that is going to be called by the reactor, what you want to write to achieve the desired effect is:

```
reactor.callWhenRunning(callBacks)
```

and

```
reactor.callLater(15, whatToCall)
```